# How to create a custom control from EditText?

Tags: java, android, custom-controls, android-edittext

I suspect this is a fairly simple concept, but I haven't managed to find the answer on the internet.

I created a main activity which formats an input inside an EditText using a TextWatcher:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher {
EditText text;
int textCount;
String numba1, numba, n;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
text.addTextChangedListener(this);
}


/* TextWatcher Implementation Methods */
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2, int after) {

// Does Nothing


}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int end) {

//Does random stuff with text
} 

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
//Does much more random stuff with text

}  

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0); 
    String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
    if (restoredText != null) {
        text.setText(restoredText, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        int selectionStart = prefs.getInt("selection-start", -1);
        int selectionEnd = prefs.getInt("selection-end", -1);
        if (selectionStart != -1 && selectionEnd != -1) {
            text.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
        }
    }
}
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
    editor.putString("text", text.getText().toString());
    editor.putInt("selection-start", text.getSelectionStart());
    editor.putInt("selection-end", text.getSelectionEnd());
    editor.commit();
 }
```

Next, I want to reuse this several times in my project, so want to create a custom EditText control, which looks just like the original, but does all the formatting and saves preferences.

Ideally I would be able to just use xml for the custom EditText to appear:

```
<view
  class="com.android.example.myEditText" 
  id="@+id/editText" />
```

I've read [Android's Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) tutorial, but it mainly talks about changing the outlook of components, instead of their behaviour, so I'm reluctant on using canvas.

So, how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Java class say `MyEditText` which extends the `EditText` class. Make sure you provide all the constructors.

Then have this class implement the `TextWatcher` interface and provide the required implementation.

You may then use this custom widget (custom EditText) in your layout as you mentioned in your question i.e. by qualifying it with the complete package name `com.example.MyEditText`

Inorder to use TextWatcher, you may also use AutoCompleteEditText instead of EditText which you will have more flexibility for this customcontrol..

Comment: thank you very much. However, when I do that, 'onCreate', 'onPause' and 'onResume' seem to complain about being undefined for 'EditText'. Am I missing something obvious? Also, in the sample API they seem to use Intents a lot. Will my code benefit from them?

Comment: When you declare a reference for the control or retrieve its reference by using 'findViewById` use `MyEditText` (or whatever you name your class) instead of `EditText`. Hope that resolves the undefined `EditText` you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Create a `MyEditText` which extends `EditText` implement all the constructors.

Then create an instance of `TextWatcher` as an attribute in the class and use the `addTextChangedListner` to add the listener

The code would be something like this

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {

    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    }



}
```